# How do you work with multiple solutions and docker on .NET Core microservices?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I would like to know if anyone is in the same context. We have a microservice architecture. Microservices are dispatched on various git repo, in their own solutions. I'm searching for a solution for our development environment.

Suppose that we have 2 solutions that runs on Docker with multiple images. Solutions can use the same images which are configured with the same ports. So you can't launch both docker-compose at the same time.

Service Z solution docker-compose images :

- **Service Z** (.NET Core 2.2), sources in solution
- Service A
- Service B
- Database C

Gateway solution docker-compose images :

- **Gateway X** (.NET Core 3.1), sources in solution
- **Service Z**
- Service A
- Service B
- Database C
- Service D

Gateway X calls Service Z.
We want to debug Service Z and Gateway at the same time because we can work on both at the same time.

I tried a solution but didn't convinced us :

1. Compile and push Service Z image to local docker repo (rebuilding docker-compose because of dockerfile args)
2. Modify docker-compose in Gateway solution to use local version of Service Z image
3. Attach to Service Z container from Service Z solution

This solution takes so much time and I didn't even manage to make it work. We have to make it simple for other developers to work on it, without setup time. Obviously, we can't make too big architecture changes.

We are running images on *Linux* containers.

Do you have any suggestion ?
Thank you in advance !

EDIT : I managed to make the first solution work but the process is so long...